# Not able to connect Mongodb with Studio 3T

Tags: mongodb, studio3t

I installed Mongodb version 6.0.3 but its not able to connect with Studio 3T and getting below error.

> Connection failed.
>
> SERVER [172.30.53.203:27017] (Type: UNKNOWN)
>
> \_/ Connection error (MongoSocketOpenException): Exception opening socket
>
> |____/ Socket error: Connection refused: connect
>
> Details:
>
> Timed out after 5000 ms while waiting to connect. Client view of cluster state is {type=UNKNOWN, servers=[{address=172.30.53.203:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket}, caused by {java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect}}]

Comment: Did you start the MongoDB? Can you connect with `mongosh`?

Comment: Yes, MongoDB is running and I am able to connect with mongosh but not connecting with Studio 3T

Comment: What is the connection string in mongosh compared to connection string in Studio 3T?

Comment: I am connection with IP address, user, password & admin database.

Comment: In Studio 3T connection dialog you can export the connection string, compare this with the connection string you use with mongosh. There must be a relevant difference (if you are not willing to provide them here).

Comment: Yes, difference is there as below, then what to do?

--in studio 3T
mongodb://myuser@172.30.53.103:27017/?serverSelectionTimeoutMS=5000&connectTimeoutMS=10000&authSource=admin&authMechanism=SCRAM-SHA-1&3t.uriVersion=3&3t.connection.name=172.30.53.203&3t.alwaysShowAuthDB=true&3t.alwaysShowDBFromUserRole=true

--in mongosh
mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?directConnection=true&serverSelectionTimeoutMS=2000&appName=mongosh+1.6.2

Comment: Please edit your question for such information instead of adding it as comment.

Comment: `mongodb://myuser@172.30.53.103:27017/?...` versus `mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?...` You connect to different machines! (unless your IP is 172.30.53.103 which I doubt, because it is a public IP) In Studio 3T you use username+password, in `mongosh` you don't use user credentials (at least not in the connection string). How can you say, "it is working with mongosh but not working in Studio 3T"?

Comment: tried with this connection string then also not working           mongodb://myuser:mypass@123@72.30.53.103:27017/?directConnection=true&serverSelectionTimeoutMS=2000&appName=mongosh+1.6.2

Comment: If the username or password includes the following characters `: / ? # [ ] @` then those characters must be converted using percent encoding.